# How to get outlines for Arc object after using Envelope Distort in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to arc a vector logo in illustrator so it matches a curve. But I need the outlines. I don't want a "mesh" as one object, because it goes to plotter to plot on vinyl.

I used `Envelope Distort > Make with Warp > Arc`. It does what I need but I get the "mesh" not the outlines.

**How do I get outlines after using an Envelope Distort on something?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the Envelope object and then choose `Object > Expand` from the menu.

This "bakes in" the envelope distortion, expanding shapes to their actual outlines after the distortion.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. My english was maybe confusing. Right now I found it myself - exactly like you wrote with Object -> Expand. Thanks again.